# How to spawn a process with an args *string* instead of array?

Tags: node.js

Does node.js have an API to spawn a process that takes a `string` for all args instead of a `string[]`?

The [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) method, which allows specifying the command to execute *and arguments* as a single string looked promising, but in reality it passes the entire string as an argument to another process, such that when I call:

```js
child_process.exec('cmd.exe /c echo hi "andrew" && pause');
```

In reality it spawns *two* processes, and because it puts quotes around my string, it leads to a badly interpreted argument since we have two nested quotes with no escaping.

```
C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "cmd.exe /c echo hi "andrew" && pause"
```

*Side rant*: why do process spawning APIs *always* expose args as an *array* when every process takes their own arguments as a flat string? Why do we pretend that arguments are an array of strings, [forcing folks who have just a string of arguments to have to parse them into an array of strings](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/63d954e0202c20011fbc0fbe2ab08980a6b626bf/node/toolrunner.ts#L82-L144), observing whitespace, quotes, etc., only to hand it to an API that will take that array and re-join it into a single string, adding quotes, etc, and leaving room all over for bugs in escaping quotes, etc.?

Comment: _why do process spawning APIs always expose args as an array when every process takes their own arguments as a flat stringwhy do process spawning APIs always expose args as an array when every process takes their own arguments as a flat string?_ Because they don't. POSIX defines that a process receives an array of strings, and the shell parses the complete string into individual arguments.

Comment: Hmmm.. then perhaps POSIX is different than Windows. On Windows the arguments are definitely rendered as a single string.